# Out Of Memory (OOMs) using Fresco in recyclerview

Tags: fresco

I was previously using Glide but it gave me too many OOMs. Then I started using Fresco from facebook. Still I am getting OOMs.
I am using Fresco in recylerviews. I have tried the following

```
holder.image.setImageURI(item.getImageUrl());
```

and

```
ImageRequestBuilder imageRequestBuilder = ImageRequestBuilder.newBuilderWithSource(Uri.parse(item.getImageUrl()));

    DraweeController draweeController = Fresco.newDraweeControllerBuilder()
            .setOldController(holder.image.getController())
            .setAutoPlayAnimations(true)
            .build();
    hold.image.setController(draweeController);
```

Can anyone tell me why the bitmaps aren't getting recycled (I assumed that to be the problem)?

After checking Memory usage, I found that the Java code part keeps on increasing

Comment: Did you resolved this problem?
I am facing same...

Comment: Same here. Never had this issue with Glide.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should resize your images in the backend before you request and paint into recyclerview, but also you can make recyclerview caches a couple of views with this line (as example): `mRecycler.setItemViewCacheSize(20)`